# Fixing cast errors in Java

Tags: java, string, menu, int, try-catch

How do I fix cast errors in Java? Right now I'm attempting to convert a string into an int so that I can use it in a switch statement, but if the given string isn't just numbers the cast fails and the program crashes. I know that in C++ there's the `try/catch` block that you can use to fix stuff like this, is there something like that in Java?

Comment: Look at the `Integer` class, there's a bunch of useful methods in there. Also, `try...catch` exists in Java also. Any basic tutorial or book should mention them, so jump ahead to that section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same in Java, you have try-catch there also like:

```
try {
    doStuff();
} catch (TheBadException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Besides that, you can also use Strings in `switch` statements in Java, no need to parse them to integers first.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that I could use strings! Thank you! This'll take care of needing to use try/catch statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try catch also exist in java. Please see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).  Also any bit of googling will show you this. Please look around at other sources a little bit before posting.  A simple Google goes a long way.

Comment: Do you know specifically what exception would arise from trying to convert a string of alphabetical characters to an integer?

Comment: `NumberFormatException` comes from `Integer.parseInt`. It's all in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class called `InputMismatchException`, which reacts whenever a value cannot be converted to the specified variable type (in your case, String would not be able to be converted to int). It would be something like:

```
try {
  //code goes here
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  //action to do in case input is wrong, such as e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
//convert here
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```